# Java Swing: Get text value from JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'd like to create a new window which is used in POS system. The user input is for an amount of money the customer has and the window has to display the exchange amount. I'm new with `JOptionPane` feature (I have been using `JAVAFX` and it's different).

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    int cost = 100;
    int amount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.getText()) // this is wrong! This needs to come     from user input box in the same window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    String message = "Enter the amount of money"+newline+"The exchange money is: "+amount-cost;
    String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, message);
    if (text == null) {
      // User clicked cancel
}
```

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: May you please clarify a bit further!!! To me it appears, you wanted to put forth one `JOptionPane` for the user, now as user enters somethingy as an input within that same `JOptionPane`, you want somethingy inside that same `JOptionPane` to change, with regard to the user input. Am I right?

Comment: Well yes - the JOptionPane is displayed: there's a text field and message field. Message field will change if the text is written in the text field.

Comment: Just use your own `Component` to pass to `JOptionPane`, and let your `Component` handle the event and the update

Comment: @charen: Just posting one small example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use InputDialog for get userinput

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
      //JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      //frame.setVisible(true);
      int cost = 100;
      JLabel l=new JLabel("The exchange money is");

      JPanel p=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 10));
      p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 50));
      JTextField t=new JTextField("Enter the amount of money");
      t.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            try{
            int amount=Integer.parseInt(t.getText());
            l.setText("The exchange money is: \n" + (amount - cost));
            }catch(Exception ex){
               // ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      });
      p.add(t);
      p.add(l);

    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,p,"JOptionPane Example : ",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if(option==0){
        System.out.println("ok clicked");
    }else{
        System.out.println("cancel clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @fastsnail, one more quick question about the code. Could you re-edit and show how could i continue with if clause if OK button is pressed or if clause if Cancel buttton is pressed.

Comment: @charen plz explain i didn't understand exactly

Comment: Well currently the JOptionPane has two buttons - OK & Cancel. I would like to do things if OK is pressed and other things if Cancel is pressed. This should be done with if clause i guess but i don't know swing really well and how to access the "OK Button has been pressed". Currently OK and Cancel both quit from the dialog box, this needs to stay but i would like to get information out of it. For example if cancel is pressed the cost of product is lowered by 5% (This is just an example i don't really need to do that) or if OK has been pressed the cost of product will raise 5%.

Comment: @charen i edited.if you click cancel ,"cancel clicked" will show in console.is that you want?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do, is to create your own custom `JOptionPane`, that has it's own components, instead of using the build in one's.

Place a `JTextField` in it, and add a `DocumentListener` to that, so that when you change something on it, it can be reciprocated on to the `status label`, as need be.

Try this small example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class JOptionPaneExample {

    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField tfield;
    private JLabel statusLabel;

    private static final int GAP = 5;

    private void displayGUI() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getPanel());
    }

    private JPanel getPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        label = new JLabel("Enter something: ", JLabel.CENTER);
        tfield = new JTextField(10);
        tfield.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.add(label);
        controlPanel.add(tfield);
        panel.add(controlPanel);

        statusLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.add(statusLabel);

        return panel;
    }

    private class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            updateStatus();
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            updateStatus();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            updateStatus();
        }

        private void updateStatus() {
            statusLabel.setText(tfield.getText());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JOptionPaneExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work great, although, this display part i'm using as a part of a bigger code so your example not really an option for me. Upvote and an answer it still is, thank you for your time :)

Comment: @charen: Actually, I did liked the answers above(both of them), just not the new edit(since it is not used in Swing).The only thingy that you need is `getPanel()` method and `MyDocumentListener` class, from this code, rest you already have in your code :-) For the rest, YOU'RE MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: @charen: Do try to copy some text from any place, and try to paste that inside the `JTextField`, `DocumentListener` will still work in that case, though `KeyListener` will fail, since they need an input only through keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
if( myJOptionPane.getValue() instanceOf String){
   String myString = (String) myJOptionPane.getValue();
}
```

Then use the result of `myString` to do whatever you intend to do.

Comment: This will give me unitialized variable. What i want is to display the string in the same JOptionPane dialog box

Comment: You can take this value and set it to the new Joption Pane element.

Comment: Can't i change the same JOptionPane element?

Comment: Yes you would have to change its behaviour a little bit, I think the answer of @nIcE cOw should do it.