# Restart and close program using JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have an application where the user matches cards. And when the user matches all the cards in the game I have a JDialog box that opens with the option for yes or no. But I am not sure how to make it so that when the user selects yes it restarts the application and when the user selects no the application and JDialog box close.

This code is all apart of the MemoryUI java file:

```
   if (cardsLeft == 0) {
   JFrame parent = new JFrame();
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(" Restart?",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(parent, "Manual Creation");
dialog.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: You need to "clear" your model (restore it to defaults), then clear all your fields on your GUI and display it

Comment: What is your question ? How to get input from a `JDialog` , or how to restart the program ? If the later, the posted code is not helpful. Post [mcve].

Comment: @c0der how to get input

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26613993/3992939

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Swing: Get text value from JOptionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613879/java-swing-get-text-value-from-joptionpane)